# Discord.js v13 the reaction role buttons not work after i restart the bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is reaction roles button command it working but after i restart the bot it say **This interaction failed** how can i fix it? is it impossible? i was use simplydjs it working but i can't change the message,when user got thier roles the bot will send message and i want change it but i can't so i use collect and it not working after i restart the bot so that why i ask this question.

```js
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = new Command({

    name: "reactionrolebuttons",
    description: "reaction role but button",
    async run(message, args, client, interaction, collect) {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Ping Roles:")
            .setColor("#0099ff")
            .setDescription("`Click some button bellow if you want get notified!`")

        const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('Acm')
                    .setLabel('Announcement')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                    .setEmoji(""),
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('Gv')
                    .setLabel('Giveaways')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                    .setEmoji("")
            )
        const m = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });

        const iFilter = i => i.user.id === message.author.id;

        const collector = m.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: iFilter, time: 60000 })

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            if (i.customId === 'Acm') {
                const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("901353036759310386");
                if (i.member.roles.cache?.has('901353036759310386')) {
                    i.member.roles.remove('901353036759310386')
                    i.reply({ content: `${role} was removed from you`, ephemeral: true });
                } else {
                    i.member.roles.add('901353036759310386')
                    i.reply({ content: `${role} was added to you`, ephemeral: true });
                }
            } else if (i.customId === 'Gv') {
                const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("901370872827346975");
                if (i.member.roles.cache?.has('901370872827346975')) {
                    i.member.roles.remove('901370872827346975')
                    i.reply({ content: `${role} was removed from you`, ephemeral: true });
                } else {
                    i.member.roles.add('901370872827346975')
                    i.reply({ content: `${role} was added to you`, ephemeral: true });
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: The interaction collector is destroyed after the bot exits. Try taking a look at the [interactionCreate event on Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate).

Comment: You Must Use [interactionCreate#Event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate), You Shouldn't Use collector

Answer (score 0):

on your filter dont forget to add await i.deferUpdate()

Also your collector doesnt seem a bit using await anymore, if u wanna use async just add await too.

At collector

```
await i.reply("......")
```

on your filter

```
const filter = async i => {
  await i.deferUpdate()
  return i.customId && i.user.id === message.author.id;
}
```

[Edit]
Also you need to end the collector after user clicked the button

```
await i.reply..........
await collector.stop("complete")
```

If you wanna continue to use that button for next interaction you dont need collector btw,

Just wrap the the condition on the interactionCreate event

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
 if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
  if(interaction.customId === "Acm") {
   \\Your code here
 }
})
```